# Parse JSON causes swift dynamic cast failed

Tags: php, json, swift

The goal is to display a result of json_encode result from php into swift as a label. I have referenced to many tutorials and practices of parsing json with swift, but I still cant understand the issue.

I referenced to an example that uses date.jsontest.com and that works fine.

In my project, I have parsed this simple JSON object to start:

```
[{"username":"user"}]
```

Here is the swift code:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // 1
    //let urlAsString = "http://date.jsontest.com"
    let urlAsString = "http://(ip address)/service.php"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlAsString)!
    let urlSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    // 2
    let jsonQuery = urlSession.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        var err: NSError?

        // 3
        var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary
        if (err != nil) {
            println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
        }

        // 4
        //let jsonDate: String! = jsonResult["date"] as NSString
        //let jsonId = jsonResult["id"] as NSString
        //let jsonTime: String! = jsonResult["time"] as NSString
        let jsonUser: String! = jsonResult[0] as NSString

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            //self.dateLabel.text = jsonId
            //self.timeLabel.text = jsonUser
            self.dateLabel.text = jsonUser
        })

    })

    // 5
    jsonQuery.resume()
    //searchItunesFor("JQ Software")
    //startConnection()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

The code runs fine when I use `http://date.jsontest.com` as the string along with `jsonDate` and `jsonTime`.

I tried to understand the debugger in Xcode, but as a new user to Swift, its hard to understand what the issue is. All I could root out is that there is an issue with how my JSON is formatted.

Any tips are greatly appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:

Here is the code http://(ip address)/service.php that gives me the JSON

```
<?php

//connect to MySQL


// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$database);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// This SQL statement selects ALL from the table 'Locations'
$sql = "SELECT username FROM members WHERE id = 1";

// Check if there are results
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
    // to hold the data
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();

    // Loop through each row in the result set
    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        // Add each row into our results array
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }


    // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}

// Close connections
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: This is not correct JSON Format. [Checkout This](http://json.org/example)

Comment: I did not consider an issue with the format. I will edit post with the php code I used to get the JSON. Please check it